# Is there's a way to check if the next page is completely loaded using plain JavaScript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I used the first page as form to receive user inputs, when the submit button is clicked, it make a request in the database, that require time to load. then the result is display in the second page.
Is there's a way to check if the next page is completely loaded using plain JavaScript or jQuery

Comment: You can't check it without server side components if you reload/load page, but you can check it if you use barba.js or angular/react/vue - your can create onepage site and pages will be loaded/unloaded inside one page. Same with native js and jquery, if you will be loaded pages with Ajax, async/await... you can wait till next page loaded

Comment: Thank you, May be I'll use vue for this project.